# add drop down to drop down

Tags: c#

i have an object that holds inside of him objects, and i want a dropdown menu from the ToolStripMenuItem a list of those objects names, and for each object, i want to show 2 values ("start","stop") (for each system).

this is how to objects looks like:

```
new ServiceReference1.CloudSystemEntry{SystemId = 1,SystemName = "ERP 1"},
new ServiceReference1.CloudSystemEntry{SystemId = 2,SystemName = "ERP 2"},
```

i did the first part:

```
 var systems;
        foreach (var item in systems)
        {
            this.btnsSystemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item.SystemName);

        }
```

now i want to add each system name a drop down with 2 options(strings "strart","stop")
how?  thanks :)